# How to disregard empty Soap messages that are coming into my Proxy

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I have been busy refactoring my sequences and proxy ( see [WSO2 Aggregate Mediator premature/incomplete/unknown completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986030/wso2-aggregate-mediator-premature-incomplete-unknown-completion/28020277#28020277) ). After I had gotten it working as per previous question , it has produced some unwanted behaviour. I only changed the names of the sequences , nothing else.

Now after my second aggregator :

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="pocSearchRsHandlerSeq reached" value="++++++++++++++=========Aggregating now========+++++++++++++++++=="></property>
   </log>
   <aggregate id="iT">
      <completeCondition>
         <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"></messageCount>
      </completeCondition>
      <onComplete xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="//productDetails">
         <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="::::" value="======================= Formatting the Aggregated Responses. ==============="></property>
         </log>
         <log level="full"></log>
      </onComplete>
   </aggregate>
   <aggregate>
      <completeCondition>
         <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"></messageCount>
      </completeCondition>
      <onComplete xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="//productDetails">
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prod="http://za.co.pepkor/product_service/">                  
                  <soapenv:Body>                     
                     <prod:productSearchResp>                                                                                                                   $1                                                                                                </prod:productSearchResp>                  
                  </soapenv:Body>               
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg expression="//productDetails" evaluator="xml"></arg>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond></respond>
      </onComplete>
   </aggregate>
</sequence>
```

Now ,it is dropping(or forgetting) that aggregated message (which previously looked like this for example) :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <productDetails>
            <productID>1452168</productID>
            <productName>PUMPS</productName>
            <productSize>7</productSize>
            <productColour>ORANGE</productColour>
            <productType>SHOE</productType>
            <sourceID>SHC</sourceID>
        </productDetails>
        <productDetails>
            <productID>1124596</productID>
            <productName>REEBOK_SNEAKERS</productName>
            <productSize>7</productSize>
            <productColour>BROWN</productColour>
            <productType>SHOES</productType>
            <sourceID>SHC</sourceID>
        </productDetails>
        <productDetails>
            <productID>1123456</productID>
            <productName>NIKE_SHIRTS</productName>
            <productSize>7</productSize>
            <productColour>RED</productColour>
            <productType>SHIRT</productType>
            <sourceID>SHC</sourceID>
        </productDetails>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And sending in this to be secondarily aggregated instead :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am getting a lot of these empty messages back into my proxies outSequence for some reason :

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 16:22:01,023] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Synapse received an asynchronous response message {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 16:22:01,023] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Start : Sequence <ackServiceSearchSeqRs> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 16:22:01,023] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Received To: null {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 16:22:01,024] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Sequence <SequenceMediator> :: mediate() {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 16:22:01,024] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  SOAPAction:  {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 16:22:01,024] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Mediation started from mediator position : 0 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 16:22:01,024] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  WSA-Action:  {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 16:22:01,025] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Body : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
```

At least 2 everytime. I have disabled continueParent.

**EDIT**

Check out [WSO2 ESB : Aggregate node droppping message after aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760401/wso2-esb-aggregate-node-droppping-message-after-aggregation) for more background info

Answer (score 0):

In the onComplete of   `<aggregate id="iT">` , you will have the aggregated
productDetails as follow

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prod="http://za.co.pepkor/product_service/">
   <soapenv:Body>
    <productDetails>
    ----
    </productDetails>
    <productDetails>
    ----
    </productDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

so you can add the root element `<prod:productSearchResp>`  to soap body  with payload factory mediator.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prod="http://za.co.pepkor/product_service/">
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <prod:productSearchResp> $1                                                                                                </prod:productSearchResp>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="//productDetails"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

No need for second aggregate and having payload factory mediator within that.

Comment: No , like I said in my prev question , an Aggregator node will terminate after receiving x number of iterated messages from Iterator mediator , so will disregard any other messages. For instance if I have 1 aggregator , as you suggest , and this handler Sequence receives 5 mssgs from an Iterator , and 1 more from another sequence ,it will terminate(execute onComplete) after receiving 5 messages , instead of 6.

Comment: ok then what did you get for  <log level="full"> of first aggregate?

Comment: In the second aggregat you need to give the min and message count.since that aggreagte is doesn't play with any iterate mediator